# Randomly sorting (by fulfilling some conditions)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I'm looking for an algorithm that can make a random sorting but by fulfilling some conditions.

For example:

> List: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`
>
> Conditions: `{(4 before 8), (6 before 1), (3 before 2)}`
>
> So in the random sort of the list number 4 must be before number 8 and
>   so on...

I need this in Java (with ArrayList) but I can't find an algorithm to do it!
If anybody knows an algorithm that does this thing please write the name of Algorithm in answer or if you have a clue how to solve it a little explanation would be nice.

Comment: Use any sorting algorithm but add those condition to it: Bubble sort is the easiest algorithm to implement

Comment: but I don't know how to add these conditions to it :( @Amir

Comment: You can write your own comparer function and use any sorting algorithm.

Comment: `Collections.shuffle()`? it will give you a random order of elements. But i can't see a clear pattern in what you wrote.

Comment: @user2896551 4 must be after 8 ?

Comment: Will any of these rules overlap?  EG: "4 before 8" "8 before 2"?  Or will they always be about two unique numbers?

Comment: Sorry @bali182 I had written 4 can't be before 8 that was wrong :(

Comment: @tieTYT Yeah they will overlap and there can be alse be (4 before 8) and (7 before 8) and also like you said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really want a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  The conditions are really edges in a graph, and the numbers are nodes.  A topological sort will produce an order that preserves all the constraints.

Comment: This seems like a good start, but won't this return the same ordered list each time?

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair criticism.  Generating any one of the possible top sorts randomly and efficiently seems like a decently interesting/challenging problem.

Comment: @tieTYT Not necessarily. In the wikipedia pseudocode, "remove a node n from S" doesn't specify which node to remove. If you choose the node at random, your result will be randomly ordered while still satisfying the conditions.